# Get categories which only have NA's for fields

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with one column showing categories and 3 other columns (col1, col2 and col3).

I need to find out which categories only have NA for col1, col2 or col3 (which is cat1 because of the NA's in col3 and cat3 because of the NA's in col1. cat2 included no or yes in each of col1, col2 and col3 and therefore aren't included).

```
col1 <- c("yes","no","yes","no",NA,NA,NA)
col2 <- c(NA,NA,"yes","no","yes","no",NA)
col3 <- c(NA,"yes",NA,"no","yes","no","yes")

cat <- c("cat1","cat2","cat1","cat2","cat3","cat3","cat3")

df <- data.frame(cat,col1,col2,col3)

end_result <-c("cat1","cat3")
```

I want the result displayed as a vector as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using `across` with grouping by *cat*, then checking if any *cols* have all `NA` entries. Finally pulling those out with filter.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(rowSums(across(everything(), ~ all(is.na(.x)))) > 0, .by = cat) %>% 
  reframe(unique(cat)) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  unname()
[1] "cat1" "cat3"
```

A **base R** approach along the same lines

```
df_res <- aggregate(. ~ cat, df, na.action=na.pass, \(x) all(is.na(x)))

df_res[rowSums(df_res[,-1]) > 0, "cat"]
[1] "cat1" "cat3"
```

Answer (score 0):

`dplyr` 1.0.4 added [if_any/if_all](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2021/02/dplyr-1-0-4-if-any/) for this type of scenario:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  filter(if_all(col1:col2, is.na) | is.na(col3), .by = cat) |>
  pull(cat) |>
  unique()
# [1] "cat1" "cat3"
```